# Ecommerce hits not showing in Google Analytics Measurement Protocol

Tags: paypal, google-analytics, transactions

Because I accept PayPal payments on my website, I'm trying to use the Measurement Protocol to send transaction details server-side. Visitors who use PayPal to pay often don't return to my website to view the order confirmation page, so relying on IPN instead is a more reliable way of recording transactions.

I've been able to successfully record Event hits with the Measurement Protocol, but although my Ecommerce (plain ecom, not enhanced) hits validate through the [debugger](https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect), they are not showing up in any of my GA reports, even a day or two after the transaction is completed. Yes, I've verified that Ecommerce (but not enhanced ecommerce) is enabled in Analytics.

Example requests, with tid and cid redacted (they are correct in the actual calls):

1. The ecommerce transaction:

`https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&t=transaction&tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-1&cid=XXXXXXXX&ti=20D95105S1786425X&tr=50.00&cu=USD&ds=web`

2. The ecommerce item (there is always exactly 1; the items are donations and my site doesn't allow multiple donations in 1 transaction):

`https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect?v=1&t=item&tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-1&cid=XXXXXXXX&ti=20D95105S1786425X&in=giveNow&ip=50.00&iq=1&iv=Onetime&cu=USD&ds=web`

3. The event hit, which does work:

`https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect?v=1&t=event&tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-1&cid=XXXXXXXX&ec=donate&ea=Onetime&el=giveNow&ev=50.00&ta=StMU&ds=web`

All three hits are sent successively, with the Event hit being the last call. Any suggestions for further debugging are welcome!

Comment: any chance you have a filter applied on the view that's excluding the transaction hits?

Comment: No, there aren't any filters that would affect transactions. Am I missing some required parameter? I've read conflicting info about IP address and UserAgent - maybe since I am sending the actual clientId I also need to send those?

Comment: Nope, you're not missing anything required. If you were, then the event wouldn't work either. Can you give an example value of the cid you're passing? Also, double check you're following the exact instructions here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#ecom Finally, try sending the hits to a different property.

Comment: One sample cid: `173780619.1493820943`. Yes, those are the instructions I followed and the validator says the full strings are valid hits. Not a bad thought sending to a different property to test - I'll try that, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it: I'd been debugging for so long that I was actually sending all the calls to the debugger (https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect) instead of the Production URL (https://www.google-analytics.com/collect).