# Google Measurement Protocol advanced e-commerce hits not showing up in Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I'm having issues with tracking advanced e-commerce transactions through Google Measurement Protocol. I want to use this because we can track sales with the most accuracy if it is done server-side. So we take over the cid from the frontend and track a sale as soon as the payment has been done. I have done this before in the exact same way but for some reason it doesn't work this time, or only works around 50% the time, depending on the tracking ID we use.

I am sending the following payload to: https://www.google-analytics.com/collect (changede UA code for the example):

`v=1&t=event&tid=UA-MYCODEHERE-1&cid=532571481.1547156684&el=91901.000001&pr1ca=weekendje-weg&ni=1&uid=1337&pr2qt=1&tr=64.65&pr1br=Some%20Location&pr2va=3%20dagen%20-%20Standaardkamer&pr2id=DRTA-4379&ea=purchase&pr1va=3%20dagen%20-%20Standaardkamer&cu=EUR&ta=Some%20Location&pr2ca=weekendje-weg&pr2nm=Some%20Location%20Somewhere&ec=checkout&pr2br=Some%20Location&pr1pr=158.00&pr1qt=1&ti=91901.000001&pr1id=DRTA-4379&pr1nm=Some%20Location%20Somewhere&pa=purchase&pr2pr=158.00&ts=0`

This validates in the [Hit builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/) and using the [Debug URL](https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect), I log all outgoing measurement protocol hits and they are always triggered and always return a status code `200`, I have enhanced e-commerce tracking enabled for the tracking id and no filters there (brand new Analytics account) but my hits never show up for this account in Analytics (even after waiting for days still no single measure).

I'm not sure what's going on, I did this before like this and it always worked fine. Am I missing something? I tried switching to measurement protocol via http or https, GET or POST, etc, it all doesn't help. I did have this exact code working for a older property but it wasn't reliably tracking all transactions, now it's just tracking none. I think I tried everything I could, is this a Google Measurement Protocol/Analytics bug or am I missing something?

Comment: I wonder if "exclude traffic from known bots" would affect this. Could you check to see if that option is turned on for the view?

Comment: Thanks for thinking along @XTOTHEL - This option is on by default, we tried turning it off but it didn't change a thing unfortunately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Ecommerce hits not showing in Google Analytics Measurement Protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895929/ecommerce-hits-not-showing-in-google-analytics-measurement-protocol)