# Missing Data in GA from Measurement Protocol Hits

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol, enhanced-ecommerce

I'm sending Measurement Protocol Hits to capture the final stage of a checkout process (Order Delivered). These Hits are sent to a Mobile App Property I am using for testing. I have chosen this approach because the information is only available offline.

The problem is that I see these events in the event report (events report screenshot) but I do not see the corresponding Enhanced Ecommerce related data in the Ecommerce Report (enhanced ecommerce report screenshot).

This is being sent as an event (t=event), while the Purchase Action (pa), and Checkout Step (cos) are "checkout and 5" respectively. The Hit Builder - Google Analytics Validator is validating the Hits properly.

```
v=1&t=event&tid=UA-XXXXXXX-1&cid=7512d264-71ab-49a7-aceb-b1434fbbd9a0&ec=Ecommerce&ea=Checkout%20test&cd1=1234d1234-71ab-49a7-aceb-b1434fbbd9a0&pa=checkout&cos=5&el=Step%205%20-%20Order%20Delivered&ds=app&ni=1&pr1id=568342&pr1nm=Test%20Name&pr1ca=Test%20category&pr1br=Test%20Brand&pr1qt=1&uid=12345&ta=CC&ti=61870&ts=5.25&tr=107.5&tt=0&cd=checkout%20test
```

Am expecting to see data in the Events Report and the Ecommerce Report.

Am I missing anything? Or is this a Mobile App Property Issue?

[image: enhanced ecommerce report]
[image: event report screenshot]

Comment: I replicated your checkout steps in an unfiltered view and sent your hit there. Sent one with `cos=4` and `ni=0` too. Both were tracked ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfAsh.png)). The [debug endpoint](https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect) says `'cd' is over the recommended limit`, but that can't be it either. When did you enable Enhanced Ecommerce in the view? And when did you send the first measurement protocol hit for `cos=5`? Could it just be a matter of waiting a bit longer?

Comment: It can't be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44058000/1913230) simple, can it?

Comment: Thanks for the update @HarmteMolder You were definitely right about the long screen name. I did a few other tests too. The test was not affected by "ni" at all. I did also remove a lot of the custom dimensions I was sending with that Hit. The next test would be to add everything back and confirm that "indeed, it was caused solely by the screen name"

Comment: Another thing that i noticed when i was that, the previous hits i sent did not create a session (probably due to the long screen name). I found this out when i created a segment of that user from that cos=5 funnel that went successfully. Since the funnel is calculated using session count information, it is safe to conclude that any report that requires some sort of session calculation would be affected. Thanks again for the good findusing GA Debugger  @HarmteMolder

Comment: Does this mean you solved it? If so, feel free to add your solution as an answer so others might use it too.